# I have a issue with an array when using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this problem and I keep putting them in the correct order but my application keeps saying it's wrong, this is all it is. The question is: Declare a variable education and assign it to an array containing the name of your college/university, field of study, and an integer which is your year of (anticipated) graduation. Make sure these elements are included in the initialized array in that order.

SO I have it like this `var education = [Cerritos College, Computer Science, 2018];` I tried this way too! `var education = ['Cerritos College', 'Computer Science', '2018'];` Nothing works though.

That is all my code.

Comment: `ar education = [Cerritos College, Computer Science, 2018];` - clearly a syntax error, strings need to be in quotes, like your second example - `var education = ['Cerritos College', 'Computer Science', '2018'];` is close ... but the last element needs to be an **integer** ... and you've supplied a **string**

Comment: Well, the first is definitely wrong since I'm guessing those aren't variable names, but I don't see anything wrong with the second. This is probably an issue you should bring up with whoever wrote the program you're submitting it to.

Comment: `my application keeps saying it's wrong` - that's a poor application that just says "it's wrong" without telling you **why**

Comment: It really isn't stating the reason why no identifier error nothing.

Comment: it's bothersome since this is literally stopping me from completing my HW

Comment: Do any of you have a suggest to write it down? it does say anything to declare a var, but education and set up the rest in an array form.

Comment: Have you followed Jaromanda's advice yet, regarding integers?

Answer (score 1):

Year of graduation needs to be an integer, no quotes.  Try this:

```
var education = ['Cerritos College', 'Computer Science', 2018];
```

Comment: Wow thank you, it's the little things I swear, I had forgotten that you don't need to close an integer. Best community ever!

Comment: @Scotty no problem, glad you got it working!  Please mark answer correct if it works.  Thanks!